# Django querying with Through table properties

Tags: python, django, models, querying

I'm currently building a web application that will have a friends feature (e.g. Facebook, etc.).

When a friend sends a friend request, a friendship object is created with `accepted = False`. `accepted` is set to `True` when the requested friend accepts the request.

Here are my models (simplified greatly):

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='receiver')
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Person(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(User)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Friendship)
```

I have it like this so I can also manage friend requests.

Now let's say I have a person John. I want to get all of John's friends (e.g., all friends that have accepted John's friend requests, and all friends whose friend requests John has accepted).

Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
def friends(person):
    friends = Friendship.objects.filter(sender=person, accepted=True) | Friendship.objects.filter(receiver=person, accepted=True)
    friends = [friendship.sender for friendship in friends if friendship.sender != person] + \
              [friendship.receiver for friendship in friends if friendship.receiver != person]
    return friends
```

To me this seems really ugly and probably slow and inefficient. Does Django have some way of doing something like this?

```
def friends(person):
    return person.friends.filter(accepted=True)
```

Unfortunately this exact code doesn't work. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to run a very similar query recently. Something like this (or similar) should work:

```
def friends(person):
    friends = Person.objects.filter(Q(sender__receiver=person, sender__accepted=True) | Q(receiver__sender=person, receiver__accepted=True))
    return friends
```

You can do a join on a related field using the related_name attribute of the M2M Model, like `Person.objects.filter(sender__accepted=True)`

A "friend" is the other person in the Friendship relation. I.e. if you are the receiver, the friend is the sender, and vice versa. I'd also rename the related names "sender" and "receiver" and prepend "friend", so the above query is clearer.

Comment: Hm, your exact solution doesn't seem to work for me. I'm getting the same error I got with `person.friends.filter(accepted=True)`: `Cannot resolve keyword 'accepted' into field. Choices are:...`

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing `accepted` to `sender__accepted` and `receiver__accepted` respectively. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad it works for you! Yes, you're right that it should read `sender__accepted` and `receiver__accepted` -- edited my answer for posterity.

Comment: One weird thing though - this seems to get duplicates (I'm not exactly sure how this is possible)

Comment: Is it possible you have two Friendship models between A and B, where they switch the role of sender and receiver? Also calling distinct at the end can help